# How to disable zoom and keep controls on UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to use `UIImagePickerController` to take pictures and disabling the use of the zoom pinch function while not blocking the camera controls when I do a `[picker addSubView:myOverlay]`.  So I create the following "myOverlayView" class with the hope of intercepting all touches so that my `UIImagePickerController` camera controls are not affected.

(per this tutorial: https://josee.me/2011/02/16/overlaying-the-iphone-camera-without-blocking-its-controls/)

```
// implement UIView Class...
@implementation myOverlayView : UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"hitTest....hit");
    return nil;
}

@end

// Call Camera...
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

myOverlayView *myOverlayView1 = [[myOverlayView alloc]init];

[picker.view addSubview:myOverlayView1];


[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The hitTest:Event method gets hit and the zoom pinch still works after the overlay has been added.
What am I missing?

Comment: You don't specify what issue you are having with the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try the following: Add a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to your overlay, and set the `*pinchGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES`? Haven't tried this, but should be able to intercept the pinching of the picker.